# DataGridView поиск и обновление данных

Tags: c#, winforms

Как при передачи объекта в dataGridView, найти нужную строку и обновить ее не затрагивая остальные строки.
Я делаю вот так: dataGridView.DataSource = editedObj, после этого данные не отображаются.

Comment: 1) проверти свои данные они вобше там есть ? 2) если у вас настроено связывание данных (Databinding) то принимать дата gridview будет такой же источник экземпляр класс или обьект

Comment: @OXYGEN да данные есть, если я передаю таким способом, данные не отображаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тут, для начала, нужно определиться, в каком коллекции ты хранишь данные.

например, я сделал небольшой пример с добавлением новой строки и обновлением dataGridView автоматически. Если использовать BindingList

```
public BindingList<MyTest> Test { get; set; }

public Form1()
{
    Test = new BindingList<MyTest>() { new MyTest() { Name = "Тест" } };

    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = Test;
}

public class MyTest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Test.Add(new MyTest() { Name = "Тест2" });
}
```

другой пример со сбрасыванием DataSource и присваивании ей нового значения

```
public List<MyTest> Test { get; set; }


public Form1()
{
    Test = new List<MyTest>() { new MyTest() { Name = "Тест" } };

    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = Test;
}


public class MyTest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Test.Add(new MyTest() { Name = "Тест2" });

    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Test;
}
```

На основе твоего ответа:
Первая форма(главная)

```
public BindingList<MyTest> Test { get; set; }


public Form1()
{
    Test = new BindingList<MyTest>() { new MyTest() { Name = "Тест", Age = 5 } };

    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = Test;
}


public class MyTest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{            
    var editForm = new EditRow(dataGridView1.CurrentRow);

    var dialog = editForm.ShowDialog();

    if(dialog == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = editForm.textBox1.Text;
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = editForm.textBox2.Text;
    }
}
```

вторая форма

```
public EditRow(DataGridViewRow row)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            this.Close();
        }
```

и сделай textBox1 и textBox2 в коде дизайнера public
Теперь работает редактирование через новое создаваемое окно.

Comment: При добавлении таким способом записи дублируются. Это в случае если запись нужно просто обновить.

Comment: @DENIS, почему тогда ты в вопросе не уточнил, как ты обновляешь данные? ты из БД заново получаешь? Меняешь ячейку в строке?

Comment: я данные получаю один раз из БД при загрузке формы, далее выбираю строку которую нужно отредактировать и по нажатию кнопки запускаю форму редактирования. После изменения записи передаю объект обратно в GridView.

Comment: @DENIS, посмотри, я отредактировал ответ, на основе того, что ты написал

Comment: да теперь разобрался. Переделал в соответствии с вашими рекомендациями.

Comment: @DENIS, рад был помочь)